# MySQL query - need assistance creating this query

Tags: mysql

I need some direction on how to create this MySQL query.

I have a table that looks like this.

```
id group name    value
1  1     user    mike
2  1     setting 1 
3  2     user    joe
4  2     setting 2
5  3     user    jill
6  3     setting 1
7  4     user    mark
8  4     setting 1
9  4     other   22
```

I would like to format the query to group users that have identical settings (IE mike and jill would be grouped in this example, not mark because of "other")

At the end of the day I am trying to consolidate and make the table look like this. If I can figure out the query to properly group them ,I will use PHP to combine the values and save it back to the DB.

```
id group name    value
1  1     user    mike OR jill
2  1     setting 1 
3  2     user    joe
4  2     setting 2
7  4     user    mark
8  4     setting 1
9  4     other   22
```

Thank you!

Comment: no, you don't put multiple distinct bits of data into a single field. down that road lies madness, and then leads to "I have these multiple bits of data in a field, how do I split them up" questions. Leave your data as is: normalized.

Comment: Fair enough @MarcB .  This is unique because the data is processed, then deleted.  I am writing an application that takes the Gmail Filters Export, rips all the data out of them (similar to what you see above) and then combines the hundreds of rules that do the same thing into condensed rules (and outputs it to a new XML file with the OR operator).  This is data that is used once and then removed after the users exports the XML file.

Comment: in that case, you could try `group_concat()` and grouping on the `group` field. if you always want to use the smallest ID as the id of the new combined record, then `select min(id), group, group_concat(value)`-type thing should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you @MarcB, group_concat() is the missing piece, I appreciate the direction!